# Psycopg Uniqueviolation: get value that caused the error

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg3

How to get the exact value that caused the Uniqueviolation exception?

The illustrative code is:

```
try:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (3);")
    conn.commit()
except psycopg.errors.UniqueViolation as err:
    print("Failed to insert non-unique number: {}".format(???))
    conn.rollback()
```

so the question is how to print the number "3"? Does the `psycopg.errors.UniqueViolation` contain the **value** that violated the constraint at all?

In the real code the values are dynamic. I log the rolled back transaction, but I'd like to also identify the offending number in the list, and ideally repeat the transaction without the duplicate.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't test the input for dupes before running the DB command?

Comment: @MattDMo ok, I probably oversimplified the example just to trigger the exception. It's a database we are talking about. Database has state. Even if I have no duplicates in the parameters, I get the exception because the number is already in the db. The only way to test for duplicates is to run a select query but I'd like to avoid it - I would need to run selects on 100% of inserts, when I have only 0.001% of duplicates.

Comment: @Alex: Do you really insert multiple values at once or is it just for the simplified example ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Yes, I do inserts in batches. Still profiling the optimal size, something between 500 and 1000 lines per batch. Will likely reduce to a 100 if the `err` does not contain any information about the exact duplicate. It will slow down import but increase number of successful transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use just the exception message:

```py
try:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (3);")
    conn.commit()
except psycopg.errors.UniqueViolation as err:
    print("Failed to insert non-unique number: {}".format(err))
    conn.rollback()
```

You should get something like this:

```
Failed to insert non-unique number: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_num_key"
DETAIL:  Key (num)=(3) already exists.
```

The format of `message_detail` for unique violation is constant, you can extract the value from the second pair of parenthesis with a regex, e.g.

```py
import re
# ...
    value = re.search(r'\(num\)=\((.*)\)', err.diag.message_detail).group(1)
```

Comment: Fair enough. Essentially it is in UniqueViolation.diag.message_detail. I'd wish it was in a more machine readable format, but I guess it is the best I can get. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexBlex - See the updated answer.

Comment: Yep, I ended up with the same regexp